# How to get String value instead of number in foreign key field in django?

Tags: python, django

Here's my models

```
class Robot(models.Model):
    robot = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    short_Description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    parameter = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    jenkins_job = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='JenkinsJobName')
    jenkins_token = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='JenkinsToken')
    jenkins_build = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=0)
    jenkins_build_status = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Never Run")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.robot


class jenkinsHistory(models.Model):
    robotName = models.ForeignKey(Robot, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    jenkinsBuildNumber = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    jenkinsBuildStatus = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    errorMsg = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    Param = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.robotName
```

I have assign data in jenkinsHistory table from Robot table. here's the code that how i assign the data

```
def Run_data(Request,id):
    if Request.method == 'POST':
        pi = Robot.objects.get(pk=id)
        hist = jenkinsHistory(robotName= pi,jenkinsBuildStatus='Jenkins-Running')
        hist.save()
```

now i want to show that data in a table in my UI. so that i have written this view

```
def Robot_History(Request,id):
    fm = list(jenkinsHistory.objects.values('id','robotName','jenkinsBuildNumber','jenkinsBuildStatus','errorMsg','Param').filter(robotName=id))
    print("hello",fm)
    rob = Robot.objects.all()
    return render(Request, 'hello/robotHistory.html',{'jenkinsHistory': fm,'robot': rob})
```

and here's my html

```
{% for hist in jenkinsHistory %}
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{hist.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{hist.robotName}}</td>
                        <td>{{hist.jenkinsBuildNumber}}</td>
                        <td>{{hist.jenkinsBuildStatus}}</td>
                        <td>{{hist.errorMsg}}</td>
                        <td>{{hist.Param}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                {% endfor %}
```

But when i got the data the foreign key field coming as a id not string
[image]

but in my django admin it is coming as a string only
[image]

how to solve that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `robotName__robot` in your `values` call:

```
jenkinsHistory.objects.values(..., 'robotName__robot',...)
```

and use that same field in your template:

```
{{ hist.robotName__robot }}
```

While at it, I suggest you change `jenkinsHistory`'s `robotName` field to just `robot`, as this  pertains to the foreign key (or `Robot` object) and not just the name. This will help make your code less confusing and more readable.

Answer (score 1):

As `robotName` is a FK to `robot` model, when you get this via `values()`, queryset returns you a 'robot'. Then you are passing that `robot` object to yout template with `robotName` name.

So when you try to show `robotName` in template, it shows you it's id
Try `robotName__robot`:

```py
jenkinsHistory.objects.values(..., 'robotName__robot',...)
```

Or you can do it in your template:

```
<td>{{hist.robotName.robot}}</td>
```